# Building a Boolean Logic Tree from an ArrayList of values

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures, tree

> [[{key:'categoryL2',value:'Screws'},
>   {key:'categoryL2',value:'Bolts'}], [{key:'categoryL3' : 'Nuts'}]

This is represented as `List<List<Key,Value>>` that logically reads :

If categoryL2 is Screws AND Bolts OR categoryL3 is Nuts return true.

Is there a way to properly represent this in a Boolean Logic Tree that can be traversed ?

Sample Structure :

```
[
    OR :
        [
            AND : 
                {"key":"categoryL2","value":"Screws"},
                {"key":"categoryL2","value":"Bolts"},
                {"key":"categoryL2","value":"Wires"}
        ],
        [
            {"key":"categoryL3","value":"Nuts"}
        ],
        [
            {"key":"categoryL4"}
        ]   
]
```

Sketch of a and-or tree solution I think could work :

[image: and-or tree solution]

Comment: I don't fully understand... Is it an `ArrayList` of json-like `String`s? Or is it an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s of ..... of `ArrayList`s of key->value pairs?

Comment: It's an arrayLists of key->value pairs, I just use json notation to make it easier to read.

Comment: What's  the  nesting level?

Comment: @WillBriggs the question initially was how to represent the expression in a tree like representation, but no one answered so in essence I solved my own issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch of a and-or tree solution :

[image: and-or tree solution]

The implementation know include back reference that will help you identify the parent from any child node